# How do steam work in micro gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, reference-frames, gas

Imagine an astronaut spills boiling hot coffee inside the orbiting space station, where do the steam go? I mean the coffee will likely form into many many balls but they at still very hot!

Comment: There is some [real experimenting](https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Videos/2023/06/Steam_bubbles_from_frying_in_microgravity) on this issue. Probably it will fly away from liquid balls in all radial directions. Specifically in this "boiling in space" video it is seen that when buoyancy force is lost,- steam bubbles escapes just because of pushing each other away from the high temperature ground. So we now can talk about some inherent steam bubble pressure.

Comment: You can do free-fall experiments at home. They just don't last very long because the ground gets in the way. Heat up some water, go outside, and toss it out at an upward angle. It'll be too hard to see when it's moving fast, but at the top of the arc, it'll be going slowly enough for you to observe it for a moment.

Comment: Can you really "spill" liquid in microgravity? I'd rather imagine that the astronaut accidentally _released_ their coffee.